# Dynamically replace part of a condition block with regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

There is a string in format:

```
else if($rule=='somerule1')
echo '{"s":1,"n":"name surname"}';
else if($rule=='somerule2')
echo '{"s":1,"n":"another text here"}';
...
```

`"s"` can have only number, `"n"` any text.

In input I have `$rule` value, and I need to remove the `else if` block that corresponds to this value. I am trying this:

```
$str = preg_replace("/else if\(\$rule=='$rule'\)\necho '{\"s\":[0-9],\"n\":\".*\"/", "", $str);
```

where `$str` is a string, that contains blocks I mentioned above, `$rule` is a string with rule I need to remove. But the function returns `$str` without changes.

What do I do wrong?

---

For example, script to change `"s"` value to 1 works nice:

```
$str = preg_replace("/$rule'\)\necho '{\"s\":[0-9]/", $rule."')\necho '{\"s\":1", $str);
```

So, probably, I am doing mistake with `=` symbol, or maybe with space, or with `.*`.

Comment: Looks like an XY problem.  Why are you mutilating this text?

Comment: @mickmackusa what do you mean by mutilating? I have an app and I need to give access to it by some guid. App sends its guid to php script I mentioned, and if the guid(rule) exist, the server will respond 1, if no - 0. I need a script that will add/change/delete rules, that what I am asking about here

Comment: My thinking is that if you are modifying the contents of a php file like this, there is sure to be a cleaner and more reliable way to adjust rules.  The title of this question lacks specificity.  According to PSR-12 standards, `else if` should be `elseif` and curly braces should be used.

Comment: @mickmackusa yes, this is an php file, but, I have already done my work, with `else if`, without braces, and all works perfectly

Comment: I don't question that it works.  I am just saying that it is not aligning with the recommended coding standard. @Oku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex pattern can be much less strict, much simpler, and far easier to read/maintain.

You need to literally match the first line (conditional expression) with the only dynamic component being the `$rule` variable, then match the entire line that immediately follows it.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NeMld))

```
$contents = <<<'TEXT'
else if($rule=='somerule1')
echo '{"s":1,"n":"name surname"}';
else if($rule=='somerule2')
echo '{"s":1,"n":"another text here"}';
TEXT;

$rule = "somerule1";

echo preg_replace("~\Qelse if(\$rule=='$rule')\E\R.+~", "", $contents);
```

Output:

```
else if($rule=='somerule2')
echo '{"s":1,"n":"another text here"}';
```

So, what have I done?  Here's the [official pattern demo](https://regex101.com/r/PomyNE/1).

1. `\Q`...`\E` means "treat everything in between these two metacharacters literally"
2. Then the only character that needs escaping is the first `$`, this is not to stop it from being interpreted as a end-of-string metacharacter, but as the start of the `$rule` variable *because* the pattern is wrapped in double quotes.
3. The second occurrence of `$rule` in the pattern DOES need to be interpreted as the variable so it is not escaped.
4. The `\R` is a metacharacter which means [\n, \r and \r\n](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php#:%7E:text=line%20break,%5Cr%5Cn)
5. Finally match all of the next line with the "any character" `.` with a one or more quantifier (`+`).

Comment: The only problem in Your and @TheFourthBird answer is that it lefts an empty line after replacement and it is not pretty. So I add a `\R` metacharacter to the end. It always works because (I should mentioned it) in the end, there always is `else echo 0;` block, so newline after `else if` will always exist. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent.  The extra trailing `\R` would have been my advice.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern does not match because you have to use a double escape to match the backslash `\\\$`.

Apart from that, you are not matching the whole line as this part `".*\"` stops at the double quote before `}';`

```
$str = 'else if($rule==\'somerule1\')
echo \'{"s":1,"n":"name surname"}\';
else if($rule==\'somerule2\')
echo \'{"s":1,"n":"another text here"}\';';

$rule = "somerule1";
$pattern = "/else if\(\\\$rule=='$rule'\)\necho '{\"s\":\d+,\"n\":\"[^\"]*\"}';/";
$str = preg_replace($pattern, "", $str);
echo $str;
```

Output

```
else if($rule=='somerule2')
echo '{"s":1,"n":"another text here"}';
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/j2adc)

Comment: Thanks for feedback, but I didn’t understand about `\\n`, why then it works in case of `$str = preg_replace("/$rule'\)\necho '{\"s\":[0-9]/", $rule."')\necho '{\"s\":1", $str);`?

Comment: @Okumaima You are right, it can just be `\n`. I have updated it.

Comment: But `$` still should be double quoted?

Comment: @Okumaima Yes because else `$` by itself would assert the end of the string.