# Secure php file from reading

Tags: php, security, curl

I have a site. I need to strict access to it. I decided to give access by guid: if one just opens `mysite.com` php calls `exit()`. If one opens `mysite.com/?guid=someguid` and guid is correct, the site is loading.

How it works: There is a php file `guid.php` with the content I mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64818623/14441129), that takes a guid, search it through the list, and if it exists `echo 1` and `0` if not.

So in my site’s `index.php` the first thing it does is making a curl request to `guid.php` with guid from url. Then, as I wrote, if it returns non 1 answer php calls `exit()` and if 1, loads the page.

The problem is that I also has a `get.php` script for cross-origin request from js. It can be called like `mysite.com/get.php?url=https://google.com`. It makes a curl request.

And here I remembered that someone told me that it has a secure lack with which one can exactly download files from my server, even a php files with their code.

`get.php`:

```
<?php

function request($url, $cook)
{
$ch = curl_init();
$cookie_file_path = $cook;

$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cookie_file_path,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cookie_file_path,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_REFERER => $url,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
}

$result = request($_GET['url'], $_GET['cook']);

if ($result === FALSE) 
     echo('error');
else
     echo($result);

?>
```

Is that code safe, i.e. will it secure php scripts code from being stolen, and pages being accessed without knowing the guid? No one, even people with guid should have access to php scripts sources. People with guid should only render php scripts.

Also I will appreciate if you tell me how secure the whole protection is in general.

Comment: that code is not safe, no. try going into ```mysite.com/get.php?url=file%3A%2F%2F%2Fetc%2Fpasswd```, what do you get? ;) there's a good chance you get a dump of your server's `/etc/passwd`

Comment: @hanshenrik I added `if(strpos($url,"file:"))
return FALSE;` to `request` function. Is it enough?

Comment: i doubt it. what do you get if you access `File://` ? or `FiLe://` ? or `FILE://` ?

Comment: `Is that code safe?` : define "safe"; what are you actually trying to protect against? This will influence the best way of achieving that.

Comment: @Martin added for url and safety

Answer (score 1):

This shouold be a comment, but its a bit long.

There is a whole catalog of security issues here - but mostly academic in the absence of a defined threat model. (I don't see how your 'get.php' could be used to access local files directly - but it does provide a means to anonymize attacks on other sites, for instance).

But the most glaring issues are not strictly security related. Why invent your own security mechanism which you are going to have to explicitly invoke to validate on every request? Why use the query as a means of passing the authentication token when that requires every link to be explicitly written to include this. Why validate the token over a (computationally expensive and slow) http request? What is wrong with HTTP authentication or cookie based authentication? What is the value in using a GUID?

Comment: `I don't see how your 'get.php' could be used to access local files directly` i guess you didn't read the comments? try running ```php -r 'curl_exec(curl_init("file:///etc/passwd"));'
```, what do you get? :P or if you dont have php-cli installed, try running `curl file:///etc/passwd`

Answer (score 0):

running this at the start of the code is probably secure enough:

```php
<?php
if(!hash_equals(sha1((string)($_POST['password']??"")), sha1("put the password here"))){
    http_response_code(403);
    die("wrong password!");
}
(...)
```

then only people with the source code / password will be able to access the script.

a more conventional solution would be

```php
<?php
$supplied_password = (string) ($_POST['password'] ?? "");
// password hash generated by password_hash("put the password here",PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$password_hash = '$2y$10$iVAZRxes2JHseW5iTLYPHe0g7VzSM3RjpeCv7Dg7W.osU5Z9M/Ii2';
if(!password_verify($supplied_password, $password_hash)){
    http_response_code(403);
    die("wrong password!");
}
(...)
```

now even the people with access to the source-code won't see the password.

(if you wonder why i bothered with hash_equals(sha1(),sha1()), it's because `$_POST['password']!=='password'` is vulnerable to timing attacks, while hash_equals()+sha1() is *not* vulnerable to timing attacks. for example, the !== check will run faster when the string is of the wrong length, and run slower every time the attacker try a password of the correct length, even if the content is wrong. furthermore, !== will run slower for every sequentially correct character the attacker try to guess, because the memcmp() php runs behind-the-scenes have to compare 1 more byte for every correct byte of the password the attacker guessed~~ by comparison, hash_equals() always compare the same number of bytes, no matter how many of those bytes are correct or wrong, hence hash_equals() is not vulnerable to timing-attacks.)